# Batch-enable archiving on multiple datasets

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, batch, arcgis-10.7, archiving

The ArcGIS Desktop 10.7 
 [Enabling Archiving](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/manage-data/geodatabases/enabling-archiving.htm) page says:

> To enable archiving on **multiple datasets at once**, you can use the
>   **[Enable archiving](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/tools/data-management-toolbox/enable-archiving.htm)** geoprocessing tool.

---

When I open the Enable Archiving tool in ArcGIS Desktop 10.7.1, I don't see a way to select multiple datasets:

[image]

---

How can I enable archiving on multiple datasets at once using out-of-the-box functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the standard "batch" functionality.

Right-click -> Batch...

[image]